# Converting cash without a bank

Tags: united-states, cash, usaa

I have around $5k in cash that I'm carrying around.  My bank is USAA.  USAA does not have a physical location or ATM within hundreds of miles of me.  I don't want to carry this cash around.  I've considered buying a gold bar and putting it in a safety deposit box somewhere, but buying a gold bar with cash is difficult, at least in this location.

What can I do to convert this cash into something more easily and safely stored or transfer it to my bank account?

Comment: Buy stuff with cash instead of credit card until you run out of cash?

Comment: Can't you buy money orders and then deposit them to your account? It will cost you some minor fee ($1/1k I think), but other than that just a trip to your local post office.

Comment: Does USAA not have partners with ATM you can use nearby?

Answer (score 5):

Go to your local bank branch. Open an account. Put the cash into the account. Then setup a transfer to the online bank. Keep only a small amount in the local bank.

Of course check that the local bank offers that feature.

One of my kids does this all the time. One bank is the conduit for when they have to deal with cash. The online one has better rates, and holds the bulk of their money.

Caution: if the money was $10,000 or more the bank that takes the cash will report the cash transaction to the government.

Comment: While "open an account at another bank" is a fine answer, I am not so keen on the idea of doing bank-bank transfers as a method to "stay loyal" to a bank that no longer serves them.  They generally offer Zelle or other hokey options as "the way to do that", and the agreement you must sign is not good, and transfers liability for mistakes from them to you.  I'll stick to traditional cheques, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Ask USAA for help!

People say USAA is a great bank.  **Put that to the test**.  They should have a reasonable answer for this problem, yes?  So call up their customer service and ask them what to do.  Expect, and demand, they have a reasonable and workable answer that doesn't involve gold bars.

Then, don't fall into ["Halo Error"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect)... if they don't have a good answer, than acknowledge that.  Hey, I'm an Apple mad-dog but I don't expect cutting edge features in their phones or top video cards in their PCs.

### Borrow a bank.

You are absolutely allowed to have bank accounts at 2 banks.  And it's not "cheating" LOL.

I think at one point, I had accounts at 4 different banks + 3 brokerages.   Once I took unemployment... the benefits were paid to a bank's debit card which was highly inconvenient, so I **just opened a bank account there** because it let me access the money easier and with fewer fees.

*Some banks have fees if you don't keep a minimum balance, but that's probably not a problem for someone who is liquid enough (and it sounds like you are). I was when I had those accounts.*

In fact, a brokerage might not be a bad option for you, since most people can use a brokerage account, and USAA doesn't have a big practice here (they partner with Charles Schwab for most of it, and that might be the answer right there if Schwab has walk-up branches where you frequent). Find a brokerage that has walk-in branches most places you go.  Deposits are generally FDIC insured unless they are invested in a risk investment such as a stock or mutual fund.

Comment: Is it possible you don't know much about USAA?  USAA is a phenomenal bank / insurer.

Comment: @HorseHair Yeah, that's called ["Halo Effect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect).  That's getting in the way of realizing **USAA is not meeting your needs**.  Sorry for the reality check.

Comment: USAA is absolutely meeting my needs.  I have a one-off situation where I want to deposit cash.  First time I've wanted to do this in a decade or more so it's a non-issue and no way I'd abandon USAA and the great services they provide veterans and their families just for this.

Comment: @horsehair heavens no, I never suggested to close your accounts at USAA.  I'm editing my answer significantly to make it clearer.  I'm sorry f I insulted USAA but you must admit there's something wrong if they're not able to handle this for you. Have you called them and asked them?  I would expect a great answer from a great bank.

Comment: It's just part of their business model.  They're a credit union with relatively few users (not everyone can join).  They refund ATM fees at other banks so it's never been a big deal.

Comment: Yeah, "refund ATM fees" is often done by banks with mainly electronic presence.  Can't you just deposit in those other banks' ATMs?  You seem oddly impeded in what ought to be easier than this.  That's why I changed my answer to "call them or borrow a bank".

Comment: @HorseHair if you cannot easily use the bank for your needs then "phenomenal" would not be the word I'd choose to describe it, just sayin....